# How to use direct and indirect object pronouns?

Tags: pronoms

I am currently studying for my French final (which I'm retaking because I already failed once). Most of the material I understand but there's one thing that I am struggling with and I have not received any help from my prof.

Here is the question from one of the assignments:

4. Rewrite the following sentences by replacing the italicized words with a direct or an indirect object pronoun. (10 points)

a.  Achètes-tu *la voiture bleue* ?

b.  Je peux rencontrer *tes parents* demain ?

c.  Le professeur parle *aux étudiants*.

d.  Janine téléphone *à son enfant*.

e.  Il n’aime pas *Adèle*.

f.  Doit-elle faire *la cuisine* ?

g.  Il veut acheter un chalet *à sa femme*.

h.  Aimes-tu *les nouilles*  ?

i.  Paul et Joseph vont parler *à Michèle*.

j.  Nous préparons *le dîner*.

If someone can either provide the answers for these examples so I can extrapolate the form from that or even better would be to explain how to do this that would be great.

Comment: We can answer questions about pronouns and how to use them if you can show what is problematic for you, and only one question per question. Please take a moment to edit.  There are related questions on the site that might help your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following explanation should be sufficient to treat a majority of the cases, including those found in the exercise.

How to do that is simple after you have practiced a little or after you have read a few  books, as then you  do it without thinking about it. For now you have to think carefully every time. We'll use the following references to find the basic principles : « [Français Facile 1](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-62144.php) », « [Français Facile 2](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-77527.php) ».

**1/** You must determine what is the type of the verb, which amounts to determining if a preposition is use with it;

- transitif direct : no preposition
- transitif indirect : a preposition is found between verb and noun phrase

Sometimes, in this first step, there is an additional problem: the preposition can "appear" in a word that results from a substitution of one single word for the combination of the two successive words, the preposition "*à*" and an article ("le", "les"); this  word is still called an article,  an "article contracté" in French. To compoud the problem, there are  plain articles  that have the same form as the "article contracté" "des".

- **du → de le**
- **au → à le**
- **des → de les** (*not to be confused with partitive article "des" and plural indefinite article "des"*)
- **aux → à les**

There are two prepositions to consider, "**à**" and "**de**".

**2/** Finally, you determine the gender and number of the noun phrase, and whether it is an animate being or an inanimate one.

**3/** You select the pronoun from the table of correspondence between combination "gender / number / whether animate or not"  and pronoun.

| DIRECT | pronoun | INDIRECT | pronoun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **MS** | **le** | (avec "à") **MS**, **FS**, **animé** | **lui** |
| **FS** | **la** | (avec "à") **MP**, **FP**, **animé** | **leur** |
| **MS**, (before a vowel) **FS** | **l'** | (avec "de") **MS**, **FS**, **MP**, **FP** | **en** |
| **MP**, **FP** | **les** | (avec "à") **MS**, **FS**, **MP**, **FP**, **inanimé** | **y** |
| (art. indéf. sing., pl., art. mass.) **MS**, **FS**, **MP**, **FP** | **en** |  |  |
|  |  | (v.pron. avec "à") **MS, animé** | **à lui** |
|  |  | (v.pron. avec "à") **FS, animé** | **à elle** |
|  |  | (v.pron. avec "à") **MP, animé** | **à eux** |
|  |  | (v.pron. avec "à") **FP, animé** | **à elles** |

---

Let's see how that works.

> a. Achètes-tu *la voiture bleue* ?

"la", plain article, therefore  no prep.,  **direct**; noun phrase is  **FS**; "achètes" **starts with vowel** →  **l'**

- **L'** achètes-tu ?

> b. Je peux rencontrer *tes parents* demain ?

Determiner is no article; so no preposition, **direct**; noun phrase is  **MP**;  →  **les**

- Je peux **les** rencontrer demain ?

> c. Le professeur parle *aux étudiants*.

"aux" is "à les" so there is a prep., "**à**", **indirect**; "étudiants" is **MP animé**; → **leur**

- Le professeur **leur** parle.

> d. Janine téléphone *à son enfant*.

prep. "**à**", so **indirect**; noun phrase **MS animé**; → **lui**

- Janine **lui** téléphone.

> e. Il n’aime pas *Adèle*.

no prep., so **direct**; noun phrase **FS animé**, "aime" *starts vowel*; → **l'**

- Il ne **l'** aime pas.

> f. Doit-elle faire *la cuisine* ?

plain article, no prep., therefore **direct**; noun phrase **FS**; → **la**

- Doit-elle **la** faire ?

> g. Il veut acheter un chalet *à sa femme*.

prep. "**à**", so **indirect**; noun phrase **FS animé**; → **lui**

- Il veut **lui** acheter un chalet.

> h. Aimes-tu *les nouilles* ?

plain article, so no prep., ***direct**; noun phrase **FP**; → **les**

- **Les** aimes-tu ?

> i. Paul et Joseph vont parler *à Michèle*.

prep. "**à**", so **indirect**; noun phrase **FS animé**; → **lui**

> j. Nous préparons *le dîner*.

plain article, so no proep. **direct**; noun phrase **MS**; → **le**

---

Let's now consider other cases.

> a'1) Achètes-tu *des pommes* ?

"des" is **art. indéf. pl.**; noun phrase **FP** → **en**

- **En** achètes-tu ?

> a'2) Achètes-tu *de la confiture* ?

"de la" is **art. mass.**; noun phrase **FS** → **en**

- **En** achètes-tu ?

> a'3) Il n'a pas *d'enfants* ?

"d'" is **art. indéf. pl.**; noun phrase **MP** → **en**

- Il n'**en** a pas.

> a'4) Il n'a pas *de vélo* ?

"de" is **art. indéf. sing.**; noun phrase **MS** → **en**

- Il n'**en** a pas ?

> f') Doit-elle faire *de la cuisine*.

art. mass."**de la**", so **direct**; noun phrase **FS**; → **en**

- Doit-elle **en** faire ?

> g. Il veut acheter *un chalet* *à sa femme*.

prep. "**à**", so **indirect**; noun phrase **FS**; → **lui**

- Il veut **lui** acheter *un chalet*

plain art., so no prep., **direct**; noun phrase **MS**; → **le**

- Il veut **le** lui acheter.

> k) Il porte *le ballon à la plage*.

- Il **le** porte *à la plage*.

prep. "à", so **indirect**; noun phrase **inanimé**; → **y**

- Il **l'y** porte.

---

*Pronominal verbs*

> x1) Il s'en est pris *à la cuisinière*.

prep."**à**", so **indirect**; "s'en prendre", **loc.verbale pronominale**; noun phrase **FS être animé**; → **à elle**

- Il s'en est pris **à elle**.

> x2) Le gendarme s'est adressé *au voleur*.

"au" is "à le", so prep."**à**", so **indirect**; "s'adresser", **v. pronominal**; noun phrase **MS être animé**; → **à lui**

- Il s'est adressé  **à lui**.

> x3) Ils se sont rendus *aux urnes*.

"au" is "à le", so prep."**à**", so **indirect**; "se rendre", **v. pronominal**; noun phrase **FP être non animé**; → **y**

- Il s'**y** sont rendus.

Comment: This is such a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a rule of thumb and easy guide for English speakers going into French.**

- If there is a verb followed by à, the object will be indirect. That à can be aux for plural nouns. `
- If there is no à, it will be a direct object.

MEMORIZE the indirect object pronouns, à **me (moi), te (toi), lui to him, or lui à elle/soi, nous, vous, (leur) eux** and answers *to* whom or **to** what something happens (à qui or à quoi)

AND the direct object pronouns: **m' or m, t' or, l'/le/la, nous, vous, les** and answers what questions.

nous and vous are the same in both!

Just two examples:

- Je peux **rencontrer tes** parents demain ? [no à, so a direct object is needed.]
- Est-ce que je peux **les** recontrer demain?
- Le professeur **parle aux** étudiants. [an à in the form of aux for a plural noun is there, so indirect]
- Le professeur **leur** parle.

Here is a trick: just use "est-ce que" for questions and don't try verb inversions. It's safer if you are not sure. So here: Doit-elle faire la cuisine ? Use: Est-ce qu'elle doit la faire? And for Aimes-tu les nouilles. Use: Est-ce que   tu les aimes? Rather than: Les aimes-tu? Unless of course your teacher insists on inversions.

In general (not always), the inverted forms are more formal. As in: Les aimes-tu? for Do you love them? (noodles). They cannot mark your answer as wrong if you use "est-ce que", in my opinion. But I could be wrong about that.

[Please note: you probably won't encounter the soi and se at your level]

Comment: I'm afraid you confuse *disjoints/conjoints* with "indirect/direct object". According to your reply, in *le professeur leur parle*, the pronoun *leur* is a direct object. It is not.

Comment: @jlliagre "le professeur leur parle, the pronoun leur is a direct object. It is not." Nope, **I didn't write that at all**.  I merely **supplied the pronoun: leur**.  Le prof leur parle. disjoints/conjoints, indeed.

Comment: You list **leur** as a direct object pronoun.

Comment: @jlliagre An oversight which I have corrected. Maybe I should have use tau.

Comment: The form of "aux" is "aux".

Comment: 1/ "Est-ce tu les aimes ?" is not used except like this:  "Est-ce 'tu les aimes' ?".  2/ There are no tricks in grammar, only logical correspondences.

Comment: What's that "the soi"?

Comment: @LPH The proper correction is to say:  you left out the word "que". There are tricks. Telling a student to avoid the inversion and use "Est-que" is a trick and it works.

Comment: @Lambie No, no tricks!

Comment: @LPH As-tu quelque chose de sérieux à me dire? Est-ce que tu as quelque chose de sérieux à me dire? Mais si, c'est plus facile le deuxième.

Comment: @LPH You probably won't find the soi or se [pronouns] at your level.

Comment: @Lambie Encore plus facile, laisser tomber le "est-ce que" : *Tu as quelque chose de sérieux à me dire ?*

Comment: @jlliagre That would not count on an exam like the one the OP has.

Comment: @Lambie L'examen demande de remplacer les mots en italiques par un pronom, pas de réorganiser la phrase. Une modification structurelle risque de faire perdre des points à l'étudiant suivant le barème que doit suivre l'examinateur que ni toi, ni moi ne connaissons. En revanche, si la phrase utilise déjà une forme courante à l'oral en français, comme *Je peux rencontrer tes parents demain ?* il n'y a bien sûr aucune raison d'en changer.

Comment: @jlliagre This is your strategy: 1) I propose something to help the student. 2) You come back with "why not just put a question mark at the end of the sentence"? 3) I say I don't think that will work. 4) You say why not use "une forme courante à l'oral? 5) The student is not showing that "est-ce que" is also "une forme courante à l'oral" and which can show the teacher he can use an alternative that is not just a question based on **intonation** but rather on **grammar**. And **I already said I didn't know if it would be acceptable to the teacher**.

Comment: @Lambie Je n'ai pas de stratégie. Je fais juste des commentaires. Il n'était même pas évident que ton *Est-ce que tu as quelque chose de sérieux à me dire ?* était lié à la question de l'OP.

Comment: @jlliagre *They cannot mark your answer as wrong if you use "est-ce que", in my opinion. But I could be wrong about that*.  It is related to it of course. I was very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Something important to keep in mind is that sometimes it's not the same in French and English: it's the preposition in French that determines whether you're dealing with a direct object or indirect object in French.

For example,

> I see the radio = *Je vois la radio*.

"Radio" is the **direct object** in both languages.

However:

> I'm listening to the radio = *J'écoute la radio*.

In English, "radio" is an **indirect object**. But in French, the verb *écouter* means "to listen to" - there is no preposition after it. So in French, *radio* is the **direct object**:

> *Je l'écoute*, not "Je lui écoute."

Same thing for *regarder* ("to look at") and *payer* ("to pay for").

Comment: Yes, sentences that will take an indirect object substitution will have an à, ones that don't, won't.

Comment: This answer makes  a useful point, however, it does not treat the OP' question. It is merely a remark connected to it. It is off topic.